# Does $\{1\} \times B$ measurable w.r.t. product measure imply $B$ is measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, natural-numbers

Let $B \subseteq X$. Let $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $c$ be the counting measure on $\mathcal P(\mathbb{N})$. Assume that $\{1\} \times B$ is measurable with respect to the product measure $c \times \mu$.

> Is it true that $B$ is $\mu$-measurable?

I know that, in general, $A \times B$ being measurable does not necessarily imply $A$ and $B$ are. (For example, when $A= \emptyset$ and $B$ is not measurable). But if $A=\{1\}$ with the counting measure, I feel like it might work.

---

• $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ denotes the power set of $\mathbb N$

Comment: It depends on how you construct the product measure.

Comment: If the product measure is constructed from an outer measure then it is automatically complete, so if $B$ is not measurable but is contained in a set of measure zero then the above set will be measurable with respect to the product measure.

Comment: @copper.hat: I thought the same! IMHO, i find it pointless to take the complete thing as the definition. One can always complete the thing. Unconsciously ading sets makes things less clear. On the other hand, if you don't want the measure to be completed, you don't even have reason to talk about the measure anyway... in this case, the question is about the product $\sigma$-algebra. Just like in topology, the question is about the projection being or not an "open map".

Comment: @AndréCaldas: I am always amazed at how many (important) details get glossed over when being taught. Even if one doesn't delve into the details, at least they should be pointed out. I suppose it depends on your focus.

Comment: @copper.hat By "product measure," I mean the Caratheodory extension of the set function defined on the measurable rectangles. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: I do not get the phrase "$B$ is $\mu$-measurable." I would assume measurability of a set has nothing to do with a measure being defined. So it would make more sense to me to ask if "$B$ is $\Sigma$-measurable" meaning if $B \in \Sigma$. So then the issue of "completetion" is irrelevant (with no measure) and the product space of $(\mathbb{N}, Pow(\mathbb{N}))$ and $(X, \Sigma)$ is $(\mathbb{N}\times X, Pow(\mathbb{N}) \otimes \Sigma)$ with sigma algebra generated by cylinders.