# Measurability of $E\subseteq \mathbb{N}\times X$ implies measurability of sections $E_{k}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am attempting the following problem from Royden Fitzpatrick's text on Real Analysis:

> Consider $(\mathbb{N}, 2^{\mathbb{N}}, c)$ where $c$ is the counting measure and let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a general measure space. Consider the space with $\mathbb{N}\times X$ with the product measure $c\times \mu$ (here the product measure is defined on the completion of the product $\sigma$-algebra). Show that if a subset $E$ of $\mathbb{N}\times X$ is measurable with respect to $c\times \mu$ then for each natural number $k$ $$E_{k} = \{x\in X:(k, x)\in E\}$$ is measurable with respect to $\mu$.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3616422/does-1-times-b-measurable-w-r-t-product-measure-imply-b-is-measurable/4479289#4479289) question is closely related. Note that the problem is easy if $E$ lies in the product $\sigma$-algebra but I don't know how to deal with the case when $E$ lies in its completion (i.e. the $\sigma$-algebra of $(c\times \mu)^{*}$-measurable sets). Any help would be appreciated.

**Attempt:** We have $E = \bigcup_{k = 1}^{\infty}\{k\}\times E_{k}$ and intersecting with the measurable set $\{k\}\times X$ we get that $\{k\}\times E_{k}$ is measurable for each $k$. But I'm not sure how this implies the measurability of $E_{k}$.

The statement might even incorrect. For instance, let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be incomplete and let $N\subseteq Z$ such that $\mu(Z) = 0$ and $N\notin \mathcal{A}$. Then $\{1\}\times N$ is $(c\times \mu)$ measurable since it has outer measure zero (it is covered by the measurable rectangle $\{1\}\times Z$).

Comment: The measurability of a set does not depend on the measure, but on the sigma-algebra of choice.

Comment: @Snoop, the assumption is that $E$ lies in the $\sigma$-algebra of $(c\times \mu)^{*}$-measurable sets.

Comment: For $(X, A, \mu) = ([0,1], \mathcal{B}([0,1]), \mu)$ where $\mu$ is the standard Borel measure on the unit interval, the completion is the Lebesgue measure and any Lebesgue-but-not-Borel measurable subset $C\subseteq [0,1]$ would mean $(1, C)$ is measurable in that completion of the product space but $C$ is not Borel measurable.

Comment: On the other hand, given two measurable spaces $(\mathbb{N}, 2^{\mathbb{N}})$ and $(X, \mathcal{A})$, I would assume the standard product measurable space would be $(\mathbb{N}\times X, 2^{\mathbb{N}} \otimes \mathcal{A})$ that uses the sigma algebra generated by the cylinders (not necessarily complete).

Comment: @Michael I think you are right. The problem as stated in Royden might be incorrect. Thanks.